# Change size of LibreCalc scrollbars Version: 6.2.2.2

Tags: libreoffice

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 and in the previous install (18.04 LTS) I had modified the CSS I believe to make the scrollbars bigger. I can't seem to locate the directions on this procedure. However, a google search revealed solutions.

By going to..... /usr/share/themes/elementary .... then /gtk-2.0/gtkrc Some directions use Mint in place of elementary, however I'm not on Mint.

Where do I go to adjust the scrollbars in LibreOffice 6.2.2.2 on Ubuntu 19.04?

Version: 6.2.2.2 Build ID: 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu2 CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 5.0; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3; Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI-Language: en-US Calc: threaded

Comment: Try the code provided in https://askubuntu.com/a/1052137/248158. If it doesn't work post back explaining what you did and what happened.

Comment: Do you know if LO 6.xxx uses GTK 2 or 3?  Secondly, where would that dir be created (gtk-3.0)?  I did look at those directions earlier.

Comment: It uses gtk3. The file to create is *~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css*.

Comment: As I was reading up on the mkdir command etc....  I noticed that the dir already was there and the gtk-3.0.  So, I edited the file and changed to 20, which meets my needs!!

Comment: @Dennis Please post your solution as an answer so that others can profit from it.

Answer (score 2):

I was lucky as the files suggested already existed (gtk.css) in the location, otherwise follow as below.  So, I just edited the value to 20px

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/gtk-3.0/
$ touch ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

scrollbar {
    min-width: 15px;
    min-height: 15px;
}
```

1. I opened my home folder
2. changed to view hidden files
3. opened .config directory
4. opened gtk-3.0 directory
5. saw the file gtk.css and double clicked it.
6. A text editor opened and I changed the values to 20px
7. save and exit.

If you don't have that file you can create one by opening any text editor and type exactly as it is above starting with....  scrollbar {  and then save the file as gtk.css in that location in the gtk-3.0 directory.

Or, follow the mkdir directions.

d

Comment: Confirming this still works as of LibreOffice 7.3.3.2. You can also check the GTK version in Help -> About LibreOffice